# Do you receive progress in crown chest when you leave or get a disconnect?

Tags: clash-royale

Following scenario:

You have destroyed already one or two towers of your opponent and you receive a disconnect or leave the app.

Will you have the crowns anyway for your crown chest progress?
And how is it shown in the match history then? As leaving or as 3-1 or 3-2 provided your opponent has finished the battle during your absence.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.

The game continues and the result will be calculated at the end. If you have destroyed a Tower, they haven't, and you leave/loose connection a second before the timer runs out (and you would have won). Then the game is a win for you and you get the crown.

Source: Personal experience.

Answer (score 0):

You will always get the crowns in your suggested scenario, since the match **continues as you would be online**. (Except you won't place anymore troops, of course.)
So, because *you get crowns for the Crown Chest even after a defeat* (Which is the most likely scenario if you quit, except if there would be a sure Victory/Draw), you will get progress towards the Crown Chest.